# Dynamically populating widgets, how to then access them?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

So, I've got a small project here that searches a path for files (*.db) and then makes a checkbox and a text control for those widgets.  This part works just fine when I run the app:

```
    # Get a count of *.db from the filesystem
    numDB = scrubDB(os.getcwd())

    # Checkbox (enable, disable for launch)
    # textCtrl (for Proxy name in controller)
    # database name (based on *.db)
    for db in numDB:
        check = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, db)
        sizer.Add(check, pos=(xIndex,0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=10)
        label = wx.StaticText(panel, label="")
        sizer.Add(label, pos=(xIndex,1), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=10)
        name = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        #Set Temp Name
        if db.endswith('.db'):
            name.Value = db[:-3]
        sizer.Add(name, pos=(xIndex,2), span=(1,3),flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.TOP, border=5)
        xIndex +=1
    #-------------------------------------------------------


    sizer.AddGrowableCol(2)
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)
```

This would ouput something like:

```
    [ ] test.db        test
    [ ] test2.db       test2
```

But now I need to be able to access those widgets to build out a command.  That list could be any number of .db files based on what the scrubDB function returns.

I'm still pretty new to Python and wxPython, so I would appreciate any guidance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working:

```
for db in numDB:
            check = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, db)
            sizer.Add(check, pos=(xIndex,0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=10)
            label = wx.StaticText(panel, label="")
            sizer.Add(label, pos=(xIndex,1), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=10)
            name = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
            #Set Temp Name
            if db.endswith('.db'):
                name.Value = db[:-3]
            sizer.Add(name, pos=(xIndex,2), span=(1,3),flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.TOP, border=5)
            xIndex +=1

    #-------------------------------------------------------
    # Save references to the widgets created dynamically
            list_checkboxID.append(check.GetId())
            list_checkboxLabel.append(check.GetLabel())
            list_txtctrlID.append(name.GetId())
            list_txtctrlLabel.append(name.Value)

            #Bind whatever events you want here -
            check.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCheck, check)

    def OnCheck(self, event):
        for item in range(len(list_checkboxID)):
            print "Checkbox " + str(item) + ":\t\t\tID:" + str(list_checkboxID[item]) + "\tLABEL:" + list_checkboxLabel[item]
            print "Text Control " + str(item) + ":\t\tID:" + str(list_txtctrlID[item]) + "\tLABEL:" + list_txtctrlLabel[item]
```

I completely realize there is probably a smarter way to manage the tuple (which I learned all about in the process of trying to figure this out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind the events dynamically -

```
list_checkbox = []
list_textctrl = []

for db in numDB:
    check = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, db)
    sizer.Add(check, pos=(xIndex,0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=10)
    label = wx.StaticText(panel, label="")
    sizer.Add(label, pos=(xIndex,1), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=10)
    name = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
    #Set Temp Name
    if db.endswith('.db'):
        name.Value = db[:-3]
    sizer.Add(name, pos=(xIndex,2), span=(1,3),flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.TOP, border=5)
    xIndex +=1

    # Save references to the widgets created dynamically
    list_checkbox += check
    list_textctrl += name

    # Bind whatever events you want here - 
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, OnCheck, check)

def OnCheck(*args):
    if args[0].IsChecked():              # args[0] holds the reference to the widget which has triggered this event.
        id = list_checkbox.index(args[0])
        adj_textctrl = list_textctrl[id]          # this is your textctrl next to your checkbox
        # do whatever you want to do
```

Comment: How can I capture the value of the textCtrl next to it?  Will try this tonight at home and see how it works. :)

Comment: For that you will have to keep a list of references to these TextCtrl widgets

Comment: *cower* How do I build that list of references, do I make an array of their IDs?

Comment: I get: TypeError: 'CheckBox' object is not iterable -- when trying to add it to the list_checkbox += check line.